# How can you edit what the run button in VSCode does?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Hello I'm wondering how do you run a script like .PS1 or .CMD when you hit the run button?

This is my code

```
$path = 'G:\Devving\Main\Shell'
$file = 'Main.py'

$cmd = $path+"\\"+$file
Start-Process $cmd
```

I am trying to run this from the little run button.

Comment: The run button in VSCode usually runs the currently in an editor pane opened script. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: the run button is a command exported by an extension and added as menu button to the UI, it will call the command as defined by the extension

Comment: what you can do is define a key binding that types your command in the current terminal

Comment: you can't run a python file as a command, you have to use the python interpreter `python some/path/Main.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is through installing a *language-specific debugger* that you enable support for running and debugging a given language's scripts from inside Visual Studio Code**, in its integrated terminal.

- For **batch files** (`*.cmd` / `*.bat` files):

  - Install the [Batch Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NilsSoderman.batch-runner).
  - Note: This only enables *running* batch files, not *debugging* them.
- For **PowerShell scripts** (`*.ps1` files):

  - Install the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Thereafter, you can click on the playback icon in the top-right corner ([image: playback icon]) or press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the active file in the appropriate shell.

---

Note: There's a **suboptimal, language-agnostic alternative** that doesn't require installing a language-specific extension:

- Selecting **`Terminal: Run Active File in Active Terminal`** from the command palette submits the full path of the active file as a command in *whatever shell is currently running in the integrated terminal*.

  - This command has *no* built-in keyboard shortcut, but you're free to define your own.
- Limitations:

  - Support is invariably limited to *running* files, not *debugging* them.

    - What UI element in Visual Studio Code has the input focus doesn't change, whereas at least some debuggers, notably Batch Runner, automatically place the focus on the integrated terminal when running (which is helpful for running / debugging interactive scripts).
  - If the active file is a PowerShell script (`*.ps1`), but the active shell in the integrated terminal is *not* PowerShell, e.g. `cmd.exe`, the script isn't *executed* but *opened in Notepad*, at least by default (this is the system-level default behavior for opening `*.ps1` files from outside PowerShell).
  - You must *manually* save unsaved changes to the active file beforehand, if you want them to be executed.

    - By contrast, running via a language-specific debugger allows you control over whether changes should *automatically* be saved; for previously saved files, automatic saving is the default behavior, and the behavior applies to *all* debuggers; see the `Debug: Save Before Start` setting (`"debug.saveBeforeStart"` property in the `settings.json` file).